# Focus on inner input with onMouseDown on container

Tags: javascript, reactjs, containers, focus, onmousedown

I have an input which is contained within a wrapper div. On mousedown on the wrapper, I want the inner input to take focus.

```js
import "./styles.css";
import { useRef } from "react";

export default () => {
  const ref = useRef(null);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div
        className="Wrapper"
        onMouseDown={(e) => {
          ref.current.focus();
          // e.preventDefault();
        }}
      >
        <input ref={ref} />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

However, focus does not work, unless I include `e.preventDefault()`. But the problem with this approach is that it disables text highlighting on the input, which seems to be a default behavior for mouse down, so it's undesirable. On the other hand, if I use `onClick` instead of `onMouseDown`, it works fine even without preventing default, but I would like to focus on `onMouseDown`.

Why is this happening, and what is the best way to solve it?

## Live demo

[image: Edit old-star-ql689t]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because as soon as you click in the container, the callback fires.  And the input is focused, but then the default handler executes and blurs the input. Now, one way is to use setTimeout - to delay the `focus()` call. So that, the element.focus() runs after browser's default handler execution.

```js
    (e) => {
        setTimeout(()=>ref.current.focus(), 100)
    }
```

Another way is to `stopPropagation` from the input element and then `preventDefault` in the wrapper.

```js
export default () => {
  const ref = useRef(null);
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div
        className="Wrapper"
        onMouseDown={(e) => {
          ref.current.focus();
          e.preventDefault();
        }}
      >
        <input ref={ref} onMouseDown={(e) => {
          e.stopPropagation();
        }}/>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

[image: Edit event-execution-delay]

Comment: Thanks for the response! However, using a timeout doesn't seem like a fully correct solution to me, even if in practice it could seem to work most of the time. We can't be fully sure about how long the default handler will take to execute. We can put a " seemingly long enough" delay, but I wonder if it can be solved in a better way. But, for sure it can be a temporary workaround to get things working.

Comment: It's not like a huge amount time will be taken by the default handler. Even 10ms of delay works fine. It's your code that "might" take time. If you think there's a possibility of taking a lot longer to finish then just add this `setTimeout` in the end of your event handler. Ther's no guessing needed.

Comment: There's another way, I had done it before but forgot at the time of writing the answer. I've updated the answer.

Comment: That's pretty elegant, the updated answer is what I was looking for. Thanks a lot for the help!